# x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match myregistry.lk

Tags: docker, x509certificate, docker-registry

We have a private docker registry with self signed certificate.

When I try to `docker login` from another node I get

> x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match myregistry.lk

We had added registry's `registry.crt` to `/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.lk:5000/ca.crt`

`/etc/hosts` has proper values for `myregistry.lk`.

We can login successfully from `docker-registry` node.

Problematic node's spec:

```
Version:           20.10.8
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.16.6
```

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes, it was a typo. I had update the question.

Comment: Did your go though all the troubleshouting steps in the doc? => https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#troubleshoot-insecure-registry

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes, we had.. it does not solve the issue. Could this be an issue with `go-lang` version?

Comment: I found [this thread](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/248#issuecomment-371068001). Although the thread is a bit old, in their case the issue was due to golang version. You can maybe trace [through the code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.9/src/crypto/x509/verify.go#L77) and see why your certificate may be failing the check.

Comment: @Rickkwa Yes, I was referring the same thread. I will try `CommonName` as an empty.